# Play Framework 2 Language Code in URL Concept?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

The manual about i18n is short: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N Is there anything more that explains the concept for handling the user's language choice?

What I'd like to achieve is what so many other sites do: put the language code into the URL

- http://namepedia.org/en/home/
- http://namepedia.org/de/home/
- ...

And then, when calling (Java) `Lang.defaultLang().language()` or from a Scala template `@lang.language` I'd like to get that value. Of course with the usual resolving, it must be in the application.conf `play.i18n.langs = [ "en","de" ]`

Do I really need to read it from the URL myself?

Also, in the routes file, isn't there a concept already for mapping it directly to the language resolving?

The alternative is to:

1. duplicate all routes in the routes file per language, or use a regex for the lang code
2. in each controller call a method for setting the language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement custom request handler and resolve language on every request. This is the same idea like your "in each controller call a method for setting the language" but you need to write the code only in one place - legacy `GlobalSettings.onRequest` or new `HttpRequestHandler.createAction`

There is a very good description about realisation i18n in play based on the url part, the only one thing - it's for 2.0.4, so I suppose you would use `HttpRequestHandler.createAction` but `GlobalSettings.onRequest`.

Guide:
http://www.flowstopper.org/2013/01/i18n-play-framework-java-app-website.html

Migration guide: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings

Custom Request Handlers: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpRequestHandlers

Live examples from my project (Play 2.4.3, Java)

*application.conf*

```
play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "de", "fr", "ua" ]
play.http.requestHandler = "plugins.RequestHandler"
```

*routes*

```
# Home page
GET     /$lang<[a-z]{2}>/home       controllers.Application.home(lang:String)
```

*plugins/RequestHandler.java*

```
package plugins;

import play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler;
import play.libs.F;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class RequestHandler extends DefaultHttpRequestHandler {

    @Override
    public Action createAction(Http.Request request, Method actionMethod) {
        return new Action.Simple() {
            @Override
            public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
                Path path = Paths.get(ctx.request().path());
                String lang = path.getName(0).toString();
                // we detect language only by URL path, cookies does not used 
                ctx.setTransientLang(lang);
                return delegate.call(ctx);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*controllers/Application.java*

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.i18n.Lang;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result home(String lang){
       return ok(ctx().lang().code());
    }

}
```

This App would give results

*http://localhost:9000/de/home* -> "de"

*http://localhost:9000/en/home* -> "en"

*http://localhost:9000/dk/home* -> "exception: Language not supported in this application: Lang(dk,) not in Lang.availables()"

Take in to attention:
`Lang.defaultLang().language()` will not return current request language. You need to call `ctx().lang()` for returning current request language.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! Also I must note that calling **ctx().lang().code()** and the **lang** parameter returns the same, so I think either one can be used.