# Play framework DI injecting Lang or Messages into Service

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I am having application using play framework 2.3.x that I transform into 2.4.x. As part of migration, I am transforming services and ran into challenge with i18n.
How can I inject Lang or get it's value?

```
class MyServiceUsedByController {
    @Inject
    private MessagesApi messagesApi;
    void someFoo() {
        Lang lang = ///How to get it?
        commentToSaveToDb = messagesApi.get(lang, "comment.addedPlace");
    }
}
```

I cannot use static because I am using that service at application start, so application is not running yet and static call to Messages fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server i18n have sense only in the request context. From the box it's based on the cookies, you can change it, to select language based on the url: [Play Framework 2 Language Code in URL Concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743911/play-framework-2-lanuage-code-in-url-concept/32750031#32750031)

Your situation - application starts, you are not in the request context, so you can take any language you like.

Suppose you want to take default server language, then just use trivial java method:

```
String javaServerLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

And convert it to the play `Lang`

```
Lang playLang = Lang.forCode(javaServerLang);
```

In the request context you can even set this language in to the context, I am not sure if you can do this at startup:

```
Context.current().changeLang(playLang);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a better way of doing that? In worst case, I can make class message provider, that will use context.lang and if none, it will use default, but I was thinking there might be a better way of doing that?

Comment: Actually that's what I finished going - creating Lang provider so it value not being set - it used default.